Flower instance not showing up in Redux DevTools
I'm working on a Next.js web app, I was using an older version of Flower React and I decided to update the package to the latest version (3.1.1), but now the instance doesn't show up in the Redux DevTools window even if I wrapped the whole app with FlowerProvider.
The app is functioning and from console logs I put here and there I'm sure the instance is active and Flower is working under the hood, I just can't monitor the data flow from the DevTools. What could have gone wrong?

In version 3.1.1 of flower-react, the flower instance is hidden by default and does not appear in the Redux DevTools.
To make the flower instance visible in the Redux DevTools, pass the enableReduxDevtool prop with a value of true to the FlowerProvider.
You can find a practical example in the Configuration section here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@flowerforce/flower-react
I hope this helps!
